# Unknown event handler property 'onTextLayout'

Tags: react-native

I've looked it up on reactnative.dev, and the Text component is supposed to have an 'onTextLayout' prop.

[image: onTextLayout prop screenshot from reactnative.dev]

I'm running the React Native version 0.62.2, and the documentation on their site says it applies for 0.62. However, when I try to use the prop in a Text component, I am shown this message:

[image: onTextLayout used as prop on Text]
[image: Installed react native version]
[image: React Native warning]

I need to use this prop to detect when the text starts overflowing into two lines. If anyone has another solution of how I can accomplish this without onTextLayout, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: Where did you import Text from? (just making sure)
I've just tested this in expo and seems to work fine.
I'll boot up a 0.62 app to test.

Comment: @Titozzz I'm importing it from 'react-native', and testing the app in Expo Web.

Comment: I don't think it's supported on web. Had to test on my android to see it.

Comment: http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/components-text--children

Comment: @Titozzz Ah, case closed I suppose. Thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: Added an answer for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it's not working on react-native-web
http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/components-text--children

Just test your app on android/iOS and you will be fine